# Check if column value exists in another column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL query that compares two values and returns an ID.

I have this table:

```
ID  Calling_ID  Called_ID
1   27          10
2   15          20
3   80          90
4   90          88
5   60          30
6   88          40
7   15          60
8   30          40
9   27          95
10  40          30
```

How do I check if each value in the `Calling_ID` column exists in the `Called_ID` column and then return the ID? The above data would return 88, 30, 40.

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you are using and better explain the logic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT ID FROM [TableName]
WHERE Calling_ID IN
(
SELECT Called_ID FROM [TableName]
)
```

Comment: Please offer a JOIN solution instead of an IN one. In my experience, thinking the IN way is somewhat of an anti pattern for beginners, and it helps them to learn joins instead.

Comment: What if, we have to check value `Calling_ID` in multiple columns like `Called_ID1`, `Called_ID2`, `Called_ID3`  ?

Comment: @ErikE Could you explain why `IN` can be an anti-pattern? I consider myself a beginner.

Comment: Please ask a new question at [dba.stackexchnage.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com). Though you might best be served by researching how to do ANSI joins in SQL. In essence, though, `IN` functions like a huge list of ORs: `Col = 'value1' OR Col = 'value2' OR Col = 'value3' ...`. This can be *really* bad for performance, especially with hundreds or thousands of values. An equijoin should always be considered superior to an OR list unless there is some compelling reason otherwise, which I cannot think of an example of at this time.

Comment: I have been trying to do this with a CTE in bigquery and it throws a syntax error. Could there be a reason why the subquery would work but not a CTE? I am new to sql and bigquery but the use case is exactly the same as in this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,Calling_ID FROM [Table]
where Calling_ID in (SELECT Called_ID FROM [Table])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID FROM [Table] as t1 
JOIN [Table] as t2 ON t1.Calling_ID = t2.Called_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement, "The above data would return 88, 30, 40," it seems you were looking for `Calling_ID` / `Called_ID` to be returned, not `ID`.  Here are two fully correct ways to do that:

Using `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Calling_ID FROM [Table] AS t1 
JOIN [Table] AS t2 ON t1.Calling_ID = t2.Called_Id
```

Using `IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Calling_ID FROM [Table]
WHERE Calling_ID IN (SELECT Called_ID FROM [Table])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
SELECT Calling_ID FROM [Table] where Calling_ID = Called_ID;
```