# SQL IN statement with multiple SELECT statements in it

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

My question is similar to this.

[Check if column value exists in another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800481/check-if-column-value-exists-in-another-column-in-sql)

In my case, however, there're up to five select statements in the `IN` statement. It looks something like this :

`SELECT Criterion1 FROM tblFilter WHERE Criterion1 IN (SELECT Criterion2 FROM tblFilter, SELECT Criterion3 FROM tblFilter)`

Yet, when I run it on vb.net, I got syntax error from this query. So, what is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Access SQL you will need to use a construct like this:

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM tblFilter 
WHERE Criterion1 IN (SELECT Criterion2 FROM tblFilter) 
    OR Criterion1 IN (SELECT Criterion3 FROM tblFilter)
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT Criterion1 FROM tblFilter WHERE Criterion1 IN (SELECT Criterion2 FROM tblFilter UNION SELECT Criterion3 FROM tblFilte`

UNION is combine together your both select stetments, but they have to return the same count of element (1 in your stetment) and same type.

EDIT:
Try this:

`SELECT Criterion1 FROM tblFilter t1, tblFilter t2, tblFilter t3 WHERE t1.Criterion1 = t2.Criterion2 OR t1.Criterion2 = t3.Criterion3`

Comment: Access SQL does not support `UNION [ALL]` in subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Criterion1 FROM tblFilter 
WHERE Criterion1 
IN 
(
SELECT Criterion2 FROM tblFilter)

or 
Criterion1 in ( 
SELECT Criterion3 FROM tblFilter
)