# boolean column of values contained in another column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean

In this page
[Check if column value exists in another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800481/check-if-column-value-exists-in-another-column-in-sql)

an user wants to get the IDs contained both in the Calling_ID that in the Called_ID columns.
Suppose I have the column in two different tables, say

```
Table T1
Calling_ID
27
15
80
90
60
88
15
30
27
40
```

and

```
Table T2
Called_ID
10
20
90
88
30
40
60
40
95
30
```

The other guy would want as result 90, 88, 30 and 40 - I would want as result a boolean column of this type

```
Calling_ID  contained
27          0
15          0
80          0
90          1
60          0
88          1
15          0
30          1
27          0
40          0
```

How could I do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could left join from T1 to T2, and check if the called ID is NULL, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    Calling_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN T2.Called_ID IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END AS Contained
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Calling_ID = T2.Called_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join with case..when..then to check if called id is null then output 0 else output as 1 like:

```
SELECT t1.calling_id, CASE WHEN t2.called_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE AS "contained"
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.calling_id = t2.called_id
```