# recursively get all child categories from a parent id

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I'm having trouble making a solution with this problem: my database looks like this.

```
        ID  parent_cat_id  child_cat_id
         1   27          10
         2   15          20
         3   80          90
         4   90          88
         5   60          30
         6   88          40
         7   15          60
         8   30          40
         9   27          95
         10  40          30
```

The context is the user selects a category for product search, I need to get that category IDs and all of it's children which can go 4 levels deep.

The database is similar to this post: 
[Check if column value exists in another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800481/check-if-column-value-exists-in-another-column-in-sql)

However the OP only needs 1 match for me it needs to be recursive. I'm still trying out several solutions but I'm at a loss. Would love some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far to achieve this. However, I will note that recursive stuff like this is not easy to do in a pure SQL query; you'll probably need a PHP loop.

Comment: If you are using the category api in joomla or any version of  the nested sets api, there are built in methods to get you all children already.