# Three columns have same values under one table how to fetch values which are available in all columns

Tags: sql-server

Considering the following table:

```
Phone1     Phone2   Phone3
123458    25689     8969860
25966     25966     123458
Null      123458     25966
```

I want to fetch record of `Phone1` values which are available in other phones columns.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Three columns have same values under one table how to fetch values which are available in all columns

Comment: Edit the question with relevant details, don't post as comment.

Comment: Repeating the title is not going help. That isn't a question, it is an extremely vague explanation of something. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SeanLange I want to fetch record of phone1 values which are availbale in other phones columns

Comment: You need to post something so others have an idea of what you are trying to do. We can't see your screen or read your mind. This question is absurdly vague. Maybe try looking here for a way to improve this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: At the very least, edit your question and post the desired results

Comment: Sean, dont be so rude :) I think his need is quite clear, but (of course) he must read forum netiquette and learn how to post a question.

Comment: @B3S I don't think this is all that clear. Not sure what is expected as output. Certainly wasn't meaning to be rude.

Comment: You can simply follow the answer in this question twice:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800481/check-if-column-value-exists-in-another-column-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer, even no question asked :D

```
DECLARE @MYTAB TABLE(PHONE1 INT, PHONE2 INT, PHONE3 INT)
INSERT INTO @MYTAB VALUES

(123458,    25689,     8969860),
(25966,     25966,     123458),
(Null,      123458,     25966)

SELECT T1.PHONE1
FROM @MYTAB T1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @MYTAB T2 WHERE T2.PHONE2 = T1.PHONE1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MYTAB T3 WHERE T3.PHONE3 = T1.PHONE1)
```

Which is the same as:

```
SELECT T1.PHONE1
FROM @MYTAB T1
INNER JOIN @MYTAB T2 ON T2.PHONE2 = T1.PHONE1
INNER JOIN @MYTAB T3 ON T3.PHONE3 = T1.PHONE1
```